# max list gnu prolog

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

*In GNU prolog, with constraints:*
I have a list, which, for N = 5 (for instance), it is like this:
`[3*(1-_#0(0..1)),2*(1-_#18(0..1)),1*(1-_#36(0..1)),4*(1-_#54(0..1)),2*(1-_#72(0..1))]`

I am working on a finite domain constraint environment and I tried this
max_list(MaxFilter, M0),

and I got this error (since the variable does not have a value at this
moment)
uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,_#4195373(0..1)),(=<)/2)

In Eclipse, I would use eval and in SWI, I used this predicate

```
lmax([H|T], X):-
        foldl(max_, T, H, Exp),
        X #= Exp.
max_(E, X, max(E, X)).
```

but I did not find any equiivalent of foldl in GNU.

What should I do? Any ideas? I am stuck and I have been searching the
whole internet for days...

What I actually want is to find the max of this list, when the labelling of the List of solution occurs (at the very end of my main predicate). When this happens, the variables of the list I am trying to find the max, will have a value (they are the same variables, for the example above, I have Sol=[_#0(0..1), _#18(0..1), ...]). But the code never reaches this point, since it throws an error when I try to find the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the definition of foldl/4 from [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) library. Try - on SWI console -
to enter

```
?- edit(foldl/4).
```

then you can study/copy the definition, that I paste here

```
foldl(Goal, List, V0, V) :-
    foldl_(List, Goal, V0, V).

foldl_([], _, V, V).
foldl_([H|T], Goal, V0, V) :-
    call(Goal, H, V0, V1),
    foldl_(T, Goal, V1, V).
```

I then tried in gprolog, and it's working:

```
| ?- consult('prolog/foldl').  
compiling /home/carlo/prolog/foldl.pl for byte code...
/home/carlo/prolog/foldl.pl compiled, 12 lines read - 1464 bytes written, 22 ms

yes
| ?- lmax([1,4,2],X).

X = 4

yes
```

Of course a less general version is easier to get working

```
lmax([A,B|T], X):-
        X #= max(A, Exp),
        lmax([B|T], Exp).
lmax([X], X).
```

works as well, without foldl.